# google is not defined in angular 4 app

Tags: google-maps, typescript

Hello I am trying to use an npm package `"@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.7",` and I am trying to implement a component that will allow me to create any of the things that I need to create as google isn't defined.

I have ran `npm install` many times.

I import it like: `import {} from '@types/googlemaps';`

and implement it like:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        var location = this.googleMapService.getCurrentLocation();

        let mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.googleMapService.currentLatitude, this.googleMapService.currentLogitude),
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.googleMap.nativeElement, mapProp);
        this.map.addListener('click', (event) => this.addMarker(event));

        this.addMarkerAtCurrentLocation();
    }
```

if someone could tell me what to look for or why it is undefined i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. On my index.html page I needed to add

```
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

in the script section.